# Remote desktop - "taking over" a big screen TV w. Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, remote-control

here at my workplace we have a 60" tv that's used for monitoring stuff. A laptop PC is connected to it at all times. I have experimented with replacing this laptop with a Raspberry PI unit. But it's not working out like I'm wanting it to; no doubt because of my lack of experience with the platform.

I've installed a tightvnc-server into the raspberry pi, and ensured it starts up automatically when the unit is powered on. That works ok. But - when I log into the server, I'm getting a 'local session', so to speak, where I was aiming to 'take over' the device, and be able to work with the default desktop on the 60" screen, and, for example, open browser windows for everyone in the room to follow.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this via tightvnc or a different remote-control application?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you want to see a Windows desktop?  Tight VNC on a Pi will show you the Pi's desktop.

Comment: @Steve: Morten would like to control the R Pi's desktop (displayed on the big TV) from a different computer.

Comment: It seems that tight VNC server starts a new instance of X Window System screen which is not displayed on the local display (the TV). You should probably search for different VNC servers.